# Alterar timeout requisição SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

Estou enviando uma requisição dentro de uma procedure pelo SQL Server utilizando o WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1, o problema é que a requisição esta demorando demais e esta dando erro de timeout. Eu gostaria de aumentar o tempo de timeout do SQL Server.

Estou fazendo assim na procedure:

```
exec sp_OACreate 'WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1', @Object out;
exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'POST', @url, 'false';
exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/json';
exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send', null, @Body;
exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'status', @status output;
exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText output;
exec sp_OADestroy @Object;
```

Alguém sabe como configuro o timeout?

Comment: Talvez o que se deve fazer é revisar a sua query!

Comment: O servidor não é meu, não tenho como otimizar o processamento.

Comment: Mas o problema não parece ser com sqlserver e sim com configurar o WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest, ou estou enganado? Tanto que acredito que você não esteja enviando pelo sqlserver e sim chamando uma página que usa sql-server no back-end.

Comment: Não, a requisição é feita por uma procedure no SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui aumentar o timeout com o comando:

```
exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setTimeouts', null, '5000', '6000', '7000', '8000';
```

Onde:

- **5000** - [dwResolveTimeout] Tempo até resolver a url do servidor no DNS;
- **6000** - [dwConnectTimeout] Tempo para estabelecer a conexão com o servidor;
- **7000** - [dwSendTimeout] Tempo para enviar a requisão;
- **8000** - [dwReceiveTimeout] Tempo para receber a resposta da requisição.

Ai ficou:

```
exec sp_OACreate 'WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1', @Object out;
exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'POST', @url, 'false';
exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/json';
exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setTimeouts', null, '5000', '60000', @vTimeout, @vTimeout;
exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send', null, @Body;
exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'status', @status output;
exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText output;
exec sp_OADestroy @Object;
```

Descobri lendo a documentação do [WinHTTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/aa384116(v=vs.85).aspx) pra C++.